# DBI selecting from tables all vs subset data

Tags: perl, dbi

I have the following code which accept input from the user if defined $input:

the code will select all the data which has field1= $input else the code select all the data from the table

```
   if (defined $input) {

my $sth= $dbh->prepare("select field1,field2 from mytable where field1 = ?  ");
$sth->execute($value);}
    else {
    my $sth= $dbh->prepare("select field1,field2 from mytable");
$sth->execute();

  }
```

i have the same code duplicated form more than one table with different data fields.

I wonder if there are an option with DBI to merge those 2 queries to one query in more maintaining manner ?

Comment: build `$where` depending on `$input` and append it to select query.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I normally do it:

```
my (@where, @params);

if (defined $input) {
  push @where, 'field1=?';
  push @params, $input;
}

# push more clauses onto arrays as needed

my $sql="select field1,field2 from mytable";
if (@where) {
  $sql .= " WHERE ".join (' AND ',@where);
}

my $sth= $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(@params);
```

The beauty of this is that you can add as many clauses as you need.

Comment: `join(' and ', @where)`

Comment: @mpapec yeah that's what I meant

Comment: perhaps space for `mytableWHERE`

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do:

```
select field1,field2 from mytable where ((? is null) or (field1 = ?))
```